# Javascript: What's the best way to compare different CSS absolute length and size value with uncertain unit?

Tags: javascript, css

I met a situation need to compare the value of the indentation(marginLeft) of `<p>`.

Is there any general way to compare them?

```
a="10px"
b="10pt"
c="calc( 20pt - 10px ) "
d="1cm"
e="1in"
```

I want some operator that `e>d>c>b>a` , Now I can only use `parseInt`, and I have to make sure every marginLeft use the `pt` Unit.

**p.s.** `calc` maybe too difficult, it's not necessary.

**p.p.s** Is there any library to compare relative lengths?

**p.p.p.s** How can I calculate the numeric difference with some unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by using the `window.getComputedStyle()` method.
This can return the current style of the element even when the style was set through CSS (`element.style.marginLeft` would not return the style if it was set through CSS).
You can use it like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
var margin = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('margin-left');
```

This will always return the value in pixels, which makes it easily comparable.
Note though that this method is *non-standard* and may not work with some browsers.